# Work vs Job in a specific context

Tags: nouns

I want to say something like:

> As I plan this website  to be my primary work/job, I will be dedicated to it.

What is more appropriate in this case, the word "work" or "job", and why?

Comment: See: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32869/what-is-the-difference-between-job-and-work

Comment: In general I would use *occupation*, but it might depend on what ... is? You should fill us in, since you want a "specific context".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you are trying to say, however consider

> **work** *is what you do*
>   The artist's life's work will be on display at the retrospective.
>
> **job** *is when you do it*
>   It's just a job, it's not a career.

It is often used

> I go to work at my job.